# conflict peer dependencies: nomicfoundation & hardhat-deploy-ethers

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy, chai

I'm facing a blockage so any help will be appreciated:

@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers is an essential peer dependency to hardhat-deploy-ethers but that will prevent me from installing @nomicfoundation/chai-matchers due to a conflict in dependencies, I looked up a resolution here https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy-ethers/issues/27 but it looks like it's not resolved yet!!

any workaround or solution that you know of. I need both hardhat-deploy-ethers & chai-matchers for testing.

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is the case for some time, one dirty solution would be to install packages using npm with `force`

```
npm i --save-dev -f @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers
```

Alternatively you can use yarn v3

First install yarn:

```
npm install --global yarn
```

Then in your project directory set version of earn to v3

```
yarn set version berry
```

Then add `nodeLinker` to `.yarnrc.yml` so yarn creates node_modules that will be used by hardhat scripts

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

then you can easily add new packages with yarn, starting with:

```
yarn add -D @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@latest
```

⚠️ Its also worth noting that you should remove existing node_modules and package-lock.json generated by npm.

I've created a tool for myself to bootstrap hardhat project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-create-app

Answer (score 1):

@codewarriorr

Thanks for your response, I found another way that is so far working hopefully it will not break my production code. I'm posting it for other devs, and if they have any other better way everyone is more than welcome to comment

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.3.0-beta.13",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-solhint": "^3.0.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.8.1",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable": "^4.8.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.12.6",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.22",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
    "prettier": "^2.8.2",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.1.1",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": {
      "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "$@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers"
    }
  }
```

I override the package.json as shown above, so I can keep peer dependency of deploy-ethers and nomiclab-ethers instead of nomicfoundation-ethers.